# JavaScript Plugin Settings Optimizations

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, plugins, default

I've finished a JavaScript plugin and am now focused on optimization, but am running into a file size problem. I've gone through and trimmed everything down (variable names, references, etc) several times and have optimized all of my methods.

The weight is all in the user settings. This plugin is meant for heavy user customization through settings only... so includes many settings. Additionally, "skins" are available and are just variations of the default settings object, like this:

```
//SETUP MAIN PLUGIN DEFAULTS OBJECT
var default:{ 'setting1' : value1, 'setting2' : value2 },

// INIT METHOD
init:function(options){
   var defaults=Plugin.defaults;
        //SETUP SKINS SETTINGS OBJECTS
    switch(options.skin){
           case 2: 
               var defaults={ 'setting1' : value1, 'setting2' : value2};
           break;
           //ETC...
        };
Boxaroo.settings=$.extend({},defaults,options||{});
}
```

Basically, the user can pass in a skin number as their first setting - which loads a specific set of plugin defaults - which can them be overridden with additional settings passed in after their skin number setting.

Everything works perfectly, but it means I need to repeat user setting names for every case/skin... Since there are 6 skins, 'setting1' will be repeated 6 times (although the value may be different). I'm curious if there is any way to condense declaring these 6 objects?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to fully understand but why don't you declare default once change value afer like that :

```
var defaults=Plugin.defaults;
switch(options.skin){
       case 2: 
           defaults.setting1 = value1;
           ...
       break;
       //ETC...
    };
```

Or use jQuery extend again :

```
var defaults=Plugin.defaults;
switch(options.skin){
       case 2: 
           $.extend(defaults, {setting1 : value1, ...};
       break;
       //ETC...
    };
```

Comment: That works, and seems like a better approach, but when having a lot of settings this answer will actually make the text considerably longer because of now having to repeat 'defaults.' for every setting.

Comment: @Aaron That's true for the first case, but with `extend`, you only write repeat once and don't have to write every settings.

Comment: Thanks! :) I saw that (and it's definitely an improvement over the code I currently have since it isn't declaring another object variable. It still leaves me with the the original problem of having to repeat everything. Your first example did give me an idea of using something like defaults[a]=value1; and making the setting names variables (a,b,c,d,etc). I'd still have to repeat everything, but the setting names would be shortened to 1 letter and reduce a bit of weight

Answer (score 0):

you can use an Object Constructor

```
function Skin(data) {//use array to keep code short
    this.setting1 = data[0];
    this.setting2 = data[1];
};    
//SETUP MAIN PLUGIN DEFAULTS OBJECT
var default:new Skin([value1,value2]),//if skin object is equal to default

// INIT METHOD
init:function(options){
var defaults=Plugin.defaults;
    //SETUP SKINS SETTINGS OBJECTS
switch(options.skin){
       case 2: 
           var defaults=new Skin([value1,value2]);
       break;
       //ETC...
    };
Boxaroo.settings=$.extend({},defaults,options||{});
}
```

or you can use an array of skins to remove the switch case if you don't need to do anything else when you change the skin

```
function Skin(data) {
    this.setting1 = data[0];
    this.setting2 = data[1];
};  
//SETUP MAIN PLUGIN DEFAULTS OBJECT
var default:new Skin([value1,value2]),
var skins:[
        new Skin(["setting1 skin1","setting2 skin1"]),
        new Skin(["setting1 skin2","setting2 skin2"]),
        new Skin(["setting1 skin3","setting2 skin3"])
      ],
// INIT METHOD
init:function(options){
   var defaults=Plugin.defaults;
    //SETUP SKINS SETTINGS OBJECTS
    var defaults=skins[options.skin];
Boxaroo.settings=$.extend({},defaults,options||{});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ffg5/